# Filter database by type Inferred from Text

Tags: database, filtering, bigdata

I am working on an app that includes reading barcodes of products in supermarket. The problem I am facing is filtering out a product by checking if he is food product or not (toilet paper for example is not food, but corn is food).

I thought about filtering it by company - I got all the Manufactures names and the next step is to check them manualy in google if the Manufacture is producing only foods or not [hopefully its one of those options].

But I have 2,500 different Manufactures...

This is an example of the information I have about each product in my DB:

```
<Item>
      <PriceUpdateDate>2014-07-06 08:37</PriceUpdateDate>
      <ItemCode>11210000094</ItemCode>
      <ItemType>1</ItemType>
      <ItemName>tabasco sauce 60 </ItemName>
      <ManufacturerName>Nitzan</ManufacturerName>
      <ManufactureCountry>US</ManufactureCountry>
      <ManufacturerItemDescription>Tabasco sauce</ManufacturerItemDescription>
      <UnitQty>milligram</UnitQty>
      <Quantity>60.00</Quantity>
      <bIsWeighted>0</bIsWeighted>
      <UnitOfMeasure>100 milligram</UnitOfMeasure>
      <QtyInPackage>0</QtyInPackage>
      <ItemPrice>12.80</ItemPrice>
      <UnitOfMeasurePrice>21.33</UnitOfMeasurePrice>
      <AllowDiscount>1</AllowDiscount>
      <ItemStatus>1</ItemStatus>
    </Item>
```

Comment: Where is the definition about ItemType? How do supermarcate deal with this kind of information? (May you can get this information from another DB)

Comment: Hi!
item type presents nothing his value is 1 at all times.
I hope to get confirmation from one of the online stores, But I dont know if I would be able to get such a confirmation..
Thats  why I prefer to do it manually.